# How to create a static class that represents what is in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table that looks like:

```
AccountType

ID  Name  Property1 Property2 Property3
```

On startup, I want to create a class that represents the database rows, that I can reference by both the ID and Name.

I want this to be a static representation (it will never change, if it does in the rare occasion, i can restart the application) because I will be referencing in my code and don't want to hit the db all the time.

I need it in the database because I need to join it with other tables also.

Can this be done?

Usage:

```
AccountType[1]
AccountType["PRO_PLAN"]
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a database? Doing joins manually can be hard.  Did you think about a SQLite db (file)? It's really efficient when it's static.

Comment: I think you can safely do this with ActiveRecord.  AccountType.all would return the collection, and this should get cached, so you'd only hit the database the first time you use it.  If you are joining it with other tables, wouldn't it make sense to just leverage ActiveRecord relations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely. Try this:

```
#config/initializers/constants_from_account.rb

ACCOUNT_TYPE = {}

AccountType.all.each do |account_type|
  ACCOUNT_TYPE[account_type.name] = account_type
  ACCOUNT_TYPE[account_type.id] = account_type
end
```

Then you can use ACCOUNT_TYPE[1] or ACCOUNT_TYPE["PRO_PLAN"] -- either the ID or the name -- to access your new hash of account types.